# Laravel "Token mismatch" every first attempt

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

First: I know that this have been asked before, but that is quite awhile ago and no one had a solving answer. In this period of time, i hope someone else has figured.

Whenever i sign out of my `laravel` application (whether that be manually or by timeout) and i try to sign in, i get this error:

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67:
```

This is the form:

```
<div class="login_wrapper">
    <form method="POST" action="/auth/login">
        {!! csrf_field() !!}
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="{{ trans('nosession.login_email') }}">
        <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="{{ trans('nosession.login_password') }}">
        <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember Me
        <input type="submit" class="btn okay" value="{{ trans('nosession.login_button') }}">
    </form>
</div>
```

I'm using the default `Auth` feature in `Laravel`, only changed the table. Sign-in works on second attempt without any problems. Any ideas?

Ps. I've tried changing `{!! csrf_field() !!}` to `{ csrf_field() }`, as some people suggested it.

**UPDATE:**
Apparently it seems like Middleware, causing the trouble. Is it necessary to use that?

Comment: It would be `{{ csrf_field() }}` not `{ csrf_field() }` just checking if that's a type or not?

Comment: If it was a typo, wouldn't that interrupt with the login the 2nd attempt as well? :)

Comment: Have you tried to login for the first time on a new browser? (Not after you logout) Dose that fail too?

Comment: Did you try to use `@form` instead of the html markup?

Comment: @Makan Hmm apparently it's only an issue in Chrome, not Firefox.
It's on OS X.

No i haven't tried the form way. Isn't it difficult to manipulate/customize data and attributes, for that method?

Comment: Apparently it seems like Middleware, causing the trouble. Is it necessary to use that?

Comment: Does it happen on your production server as well as your development environment?

Comment: @StevenThelin if you're talking about the verifycsrftoken middleware, yes it is important to use it in production, in development not so much

Comment: Hmm that's annoying. Are there any way to display this error different? I managed to read through 'ze webz, and find that it's cause by a timed-out session expiration. It doesn't occur on a fresh start.

Comment: Just put a breakpoint in the VerifyCrsfToken class when it tries to match the token you pass with the session id and see if they are matching.

Comment: It seems to occur every time the user is logged out due to session expiration. Are there any way to disable the Laravel Session expire?